# Python Context Manager supporting both Async and Sync Calls

Tags: python, asynchronous, python-asyncio, contextmanager

I'm building a Context Manager that is initialised/injected with a Factory, that creates resource instances that will then be managed by the context manager.

I have two different Factories:
Factory
AsyncFactory

Where one creates a standard version of the resource. And the other creates a Async version of the resource.

At the moment I have two context managers: ContextManager and AsyncContextManager. While looking at my code I am aware that both the Context managers **init** and helper functions are identical across both implementations.

One option is to create a BaseContextManager, and then inherit this common functionality.

The other would be to merge into a single context manager, that has both **enter**, **exit** and **aenter**, **aexit** method implementations. ie

```
class ContextManager

    def __init__(self, a, b, c)
       ...

    def __enter__(self):
       ...

    def __exit__(self):
       ...

    def __aenter__(self):
       ...

    def __aexit__(self):
       ...

    def helper()
      ...
```

and then depending one whether called "with" or "async with", it would work in an async manner or not.

Wondering what peoples thoughts are on this type of Context Manager. My initial feeling i keeping them as two managers so to avoid doing to much in one class, but am interested in other view points.

Comment: [PEP 492](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0492/#why-not-reuse-existing-magic-names) explicitly calls out the ability to have a single class act as both a synchronous and asynchronous context manager as the rationale for introducing `__aenter__` and `__aexit__`, rather than simply declaring `async def __enter__(self):...`.

Comment: Ah great. I didn't see that. A pretty good endorsement that this is accepted path to take.